# How to adjust/set UIView size according to UILabel content

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uilabel

i used loop to create dynamic `UIView`.  But i could not create `UIView` according the size of `UILabel` kindly help me as i could do further proceed.. need your help.. i will appreciate

```
for(NSString *item in myArray)
{
    length = item.length;
    self.custom=[[CustomView alloc]init];
    self.custom.Label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, yAxis, 100+item.length, 44)];
    [self.custom setFrame:self.custom.Label.frame];

    [self.custom sizeToFit];

    yAxis=yAxis+50;

    self.custom.tag=200+a;
    a++;

    [newViews addObject:self.custom];
    length = item.length;

    self.custom.Label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,5,length+20,40)];

    self.custom.button=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(85,10,12,10)];

    [self.custom.Label setText:item];

    // Tell the label to use an unlimited number of lines
    [self.custom.Label setNumberOfLines:1];
    [self.custom.Label sizeToFit];
    self.custom.Label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

    ![this is image i have created uiview according the array values where uilabel more width than uiview so i need to set uiview according the uilabel][1]

    UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button_droparrow.png"];
    [self.custom.button setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.custom.button addTarget:self
                           action:@selector(buttonPressed:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    self.custom.button.tag=self.custom.button.tag+a;
    self.custom.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    custom.Label.text=item;
    custom.Label.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    [self.custom addSubview:self.custom.button];
    [self.custom addSubview:custom.Label];
    // [self.custom addSubview:cv];

    [self.view addSubview:self.custom];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the size based of the `UILabel` content using the following code.

```
 NSString * countString = aLbl.text;
CGSize s = [countString sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Light" size:12] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(100, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

And alter the Size of any views using following code

```
CGRect  rect = aView.frame;
rect.size.width = s.width;
rect.size.height = s.height;
aView.frame = rect;
```

Comment: repost your out put image

Comment: My score is less than 10 so I could link image

Comment: I could not post my score is less than 10

Comment: upload some where else and post link here.

Comment: after assigning the text,did you used the above code?

Comment: you are setting frame after allocating `uilable`.  add the below line `[self.custom setFrame:self.custom.Label.frame];` after allocating `self.custom.Label`

Answer (score 0):

try size to fit for label or view

```
[yourlabel sizeToFit];
```

or

```
[yourview sizeToFit];
```

Answer (score -1):

Change setNumberOfLines:0 and run your app. I hope it helps you. And I request to you, if this is help you please vote me.

```
[self.custom.Label setNumberOfLines:0];

self.custom.Label.text = @"xyz.................";
[self.custom.Label sizeToFit];
```